# ERROR: syntax error at or near "OVER"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to the SQL language and PostgreSQL. I was getting familiar with the language and was following a PostgreSQL tutorial until I got stuck at a chapter about Window Functions ([link text](http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/tutorial-window.html). I created the exact same table 'empsalary' as shown in the example:

```
wtouw=# SELECT * FROM empsalary;
  depname  | empno | salary 
-----------+-------+--------
 develop   |    11 |   5200
 develop   |     7 |   4200
 develop   |     9 |   4500
 develop   |     8 |   6000
 develop   |    10 |   5200
 personnel |     5 |   3500
 personnel |     2 |   3900
 sales     |     3 |   4800
 sales     |     1 |   5000
 sales     |     4 |   4800
(10 rows)
```

and copy-pasted the first statement that uses a window function:

```
SELECT depname, empno, salary, avg(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY depname) FROM empsalary;
```

However, I got the following error message:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "OVER"
LINE 1: SELECT depname, empno, salary, avg(salary) OVER (PARTITION B...
                                                   ^
```

Other efforts to use the OVER clause also didn't work. 
What did I do wrong?

Thanks.

Version info:
PostgreSQL 8.3.8 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC cc (GCC) 4.2.4 (Ubuntu 4.2.4-1ubuntu3)

Comment: So you read the 8.5 dev docs but try what they say with 8.3?

Comment: @MilenA.Radev: there never was a 8.5 release.

Comment: @wtouw: 8.3 is no longer supported you should upgrade to 9.2 as soon as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it possible that this is not supported by your version?

From [3.5. Window Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/tutorial-window.html) you use the exact same function

> Here is an example that shows how to
>   compare each employee's salary with
>   the average salary in his or her
>   department:
>
> SELECT depname, empno, salary,
>   avg(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY
>   depname) FROM empsalary;

but it states

> PostgreSQL 8.4.1 Documentation

Comment: OVER is a reserved SQL keyword (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) for PostgreSQL 8.3.8

Comment: Yes, but it does not seem that 8.3.8 supports Window Functions.

Comment: astander is correct, window functions were introduced to Postgresql in 8.4:  http://people.planetpostgresql.org/andrew/index.php?/archives/29-First-play-with-window-functions.html

Comment: (And I just find it amusing ... the doc wtouw linked to in fact states "the presence of a key word does not indicate the existence of a feature.")