# how to select/find the table data along with the latest associated (many to many) data

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-postgresql

I have following relation in my tables

item.rb

```
has_one :item_shipping_detail
```

item_shipping_detail.rb

```
belongs_to  :item
has_many :shipping_statuses
```

status.rb

```
belongs_to  :item_shipping_detail
```

Ex. Data

items

```
id   title     city      state             country
 1   Title1    Nagpur    Maharashtra       India
```

item_shipping_details

```
id   item_id    price     description
 1   1          10        Electronic
```

Statuses

```
id   item_shipping_detail_id    status_city     status_state   status_country  created_at 
 1   1                           Mumbai         Maharashtra    India           2012-01-09 07:58:16
 2   1                           Akola          Maharashtra    India           2012-01-10 07:58:16
 3   1                           Nagpur         Maharashtra    India           2012-01-11 07:58:16
```

I want the following result (item, item_shipping_details, statuses `(LATEST or MAX)`) using single query

```
id title city     state         country  price  description  status_city  status_state    status_country
 1 Title1 Nagpur  Maharashtra    India    10    Electronic   Nagpur       Maharashtra    India
```

JYI:- I am using Rails 2.3.8

Comment: Are the three status_city columns in your statuses table actually status_city, status_state and status_country respectively?

Comment: Yes Mark it's just typo but i edited the question.

Comment: Which version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: ok it's my fault but is there any way to build a query for this?

Comment: Gary's answer is definitely worth trying.

Comment: Answer added using an aggregate sub-query instead of a correlated `NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
select i.id,
       i.title,
       i.city,
       i.state,
       i.country,
       d.price,
       d.description,
       s.status_city,
       s.status_state,
       s.status_country
from items i
left join item_shipping_details d on i.id = d.item_id
left join 
   (select s1.* from statuses s1
     where not exists 
           (select * from statuses s2
        where 
                s2.item_shipping_detail_id = s1.item_shipping_detail_id 
                and s2.created_at> s1.created_at) )  s
on d.id = s.item_shipping_detail_id
```

The where clause on the subselect filters out any record where there is a newer record.  This is effectively the same as Mark Bannister's query (which works fine on my Postgresql 9.1 database), but doesn't use the partition functions.

It probably isn't as efficient as partition functions so if you can work out why yours isn't running (maybe a 8.4 compatibility setting or something?) I'd go with his query.

Comment: +1 I have now deleted my answer, as Salil has revealed that the result of a `select version();` statement is "PostgreSQL 8.3.8 on i386-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 4.3.2 20081105 (Red Hat 4.3.2-7) ". In other words, he is running a version of Postgres which (from comments on the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872705/error-syntax-error-at-or-near-over ) does not support Window Functions.

Comment: I also upvoted you but this is too slow, is there any efficient way to do that i have very large amount of data.

Comment: To address performance issues we're gonna need a lot more information.  How many rows in each table?   What fields are indexed?   Are you querying for whole table or an individual item?

Comment: Actually it might be worth raising as a separate question so more people can see it.

Answer (score 2):

Use DISTINCT ON, a postgresql extension:

```
select distinct on(i.id, d.id)
   i.id,
   i.title,
   i.city,
   i.state,
   i.country,
   d.price,
   d.description,
   s.status_city,
   s.status_state,
   s.status_country
from items i
left join item_shipping_details d on i.id = d.item_id
left join statuses s on s.item_shipping_detail_id = d.id
order by i.id, d.id, s.created_at desc
```

Also consider standard syntax:

```
select * from (
select i.id,
   i.title,
   i.city,
   i.state,
   i.country,
   d.price,
   d.description,
   s.status_city,
   s.status_state,
   s.status_country,
   row_number() over(partition by d.id, i.id order by s.created_at desc) as rn
from items i
left join item_shipping_details d on i.id = d.item_id
left join statuses s on s.item_shipping_detail_id = d.id
) tab where tab.rn = 1
```

Comment: Appear that the OP is using 8.3.8 which doesn't have window functions.

Comment: "PostgreSQL Version is 9.1.2 – Salil Jan 19 at 6:02" . Also, the DISTINCT ON version is relevant from at least 7.1

Comment: I only commented on window functions, not DISTINCT ON :)  Regading the version, check first comment to Gary's answer.  He may have *originally stated* `9.1.2`, but then he helpfully changed his mind in a comment on a now deleted answer...

Answer (score 0):

You must include "something" to the statuses, so you can select the latest status, like an arrival date or so. There is no way to answer your question  before you provide that extra column.

Comment: See my Edited question, i have added 'created_at' column in statuses table.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out that you're using `8.3.8` (from a comment on a deleted answer) you can't use `row_number()`.  This means that I tend to join on a aggregate sub-query to determine which record is the newest.  Something like...

```
SELECT
   i.id,
   i.title,
   i.city,
   i.state,
   i.country,
   d.price,
   d.description,
   s.status_city,
   s.status_state,
   s.status_country
FROM
  items                    i
LEFT JOIN
  item_shipping_details    d
    ON i.id = d.item_id
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT item_shipping_detail_id, MAX(created_at) AS created_at FROM statuses GROUP BY item_shipping_detail_id)   lookup
    ON lookup.item_shipping_detail_id = d.id
LEFT JOIN
  statuses                 s
    ON  s.item_shipping_detail_id = lookup.item_shipping_detail_id
    AND s.created_at              = lookup.created_at
```

***Note:***  To optimise the sub-query and join, the `statuses` table does need to be indexed appropriately; `(item_shipping_detail_id, created_at)`

If you have an index on `(item_shipping_detail_id, id)` instead, and you can guarantee that a higher `id` *always* means a record is newer than one with a lower `id`, you *can* replace occurances of `created_at` with `id` in my query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select distinct on(i.id, d.id)
   i.id,
   i.title,
   i.city,
   i.state,
   i.country,
   d.price,
   d.description,
   s.status_city,
   s.status_state,
   s.status_country
from items i
left join item_shipping_details d on i.id = d.item_id
left join statuses s on s.item_shipping_detail_id = d.id
where s.id = (select Max(id) as id from statuses where item_shipping_detail_id = d.id)
order by i.id, d.id desc
```

Comment: In my experience, this correlated sub-query approach is logically identical to but slower than joining on an uncorrelated sub-query.